# Cross platform component react-native-web

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

I use **react-native-web** and I would like to create cross-platform components. I would like to differentiate each components **by platform**.

So I followed this tutorial: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/

I have 3 files :
     - friendsList.android.js
     - friendsList.ios.js
     - friendsList.web.js

And for import `FriendsList`, in the `index.android.js`, `index.ios.js` `index.web.js` :

```
Import FriendsList from './friendsList';
```

On Ios and Android, it works fine. But on the web, it does not recognize the file. I actually have 3 solutions:
- **specify when importing**: `import FriendsList from './friendsList.web';`
     - **define a service who dispatch for each platform**
- or to **define an alias in webpack**:

```
 resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react-native': 'react-native-web',
            './friendsList': './friendsList.web',
        },
    },
```

Is there a way to import .web without this ways ?
Maybe it's not thought to do like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `react-native-web` [getting started](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/docs/guides/getting-started.md) documentation, you need to set the extensions.

```
resolve: {
  // Maps the 'react-native' import to 'react-native-web'.
  alias: {
    'react-native': 'react-native-web'
  },
  // If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific
  // module implementations should be written in files using the extension
  // `.web.js`.
  extensions: [ '.web.js', '.js' ]
}
```